# How to avoid duplicate code blocks here

Tags: android

Novice here. Two buttons, note1 and note2, will display the same AlertDialog when clicked, and then store the user's choice separatedly. Trying to avoid duplicate code I run into problems, I am shure there is an easy way, but I can not find it. Thanks

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // respond to clicks
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnNote1) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.selNoteBtn).setSingleChoiceItems(notes, 0,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        note1.setText(which);
                    }
                });
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnNote2) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.selNoteBtn).setSingleChoiceItems(notes, 0,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        note2.setText(which);
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know why but instead of up voting or suggesting some small edits everybody is writing the same answer again and again. It is not what expected here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a ViewID variable that is final so that you can reference it in the `onClick()`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final int viewID = v.getId();

    // respond to clicks
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.selNoteBtn).setSingleChoiceItems(notes, 0,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if(viewID == R.id.btnNote1) {
                    note1.setText(which);
                } else {
                    note2.setText(which);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This was my approach, I just needed the "final" touch. It works but I don´t understand why it's neccesary. Thanks

Comment: Just make sure if you want to add any other buttons or clickable items that you add conditions again. Or you will get an alertdialog for everything. Similar to my post below (but this is the best choice for your answer)

Comment: @PedroGonzalez The reason you need the `final` modifier is because the `onClick` is a separate method outside of the `onClick` context.  The final just says that you can access it in any of the methods in (and under) the `onClick` context.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the conditional inside the onClick function right before the `noteN.setText(which);` statement, since that's the only thing that changes between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the EditText (or whatever note1 and note2 are based on the ID and the use that in the button Listener.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // respond to clicks
    EditText note;
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnNote1) {
        note = note1;
    } else {
        note = note2;
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.selNoteBtn).setSingleChoiceItems(notes, 0,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    note.setText(which);
            }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // respond to clicks
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.selNoteBtn).setSingleChoiceItems(notes, 0,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnNote1)
                       note1.setText(which);
                    else
                       note2.setText(which);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use onClick() for **OTHER** items as well use this method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // respond to clicks
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnNote1 || v.getId() == R.id.btnNote2) {
       showAlerts(View v)
    }
}

private void showAlerts(View v)
{
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.selNoteBtn).setSingleChoiceItems(notes, 0,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnNote2)note2.setText(which);
                        else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnNote1)note1.setText(which);
                    }
      });
}
```